# Bootstrap: Changing break point for off-canvas navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using bootstrap off-canvas navigation you can see working version

http://www.bootply.com/96266

left navigation goes off canvas on small screen. Can someone help me to change break point of the navigation so that we its always off-canvas even on large screens

Comment: Please provide source code here and don't link to some external service

Comment: that is bootply link , please check  www.bootply.com/96266#